# Android Studio login Function with database reference

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Cant seem to crack my head even after following tutorials. Please help.

Should I be using firebase auth instead? Or are my database reference wrong?
Am able to start the app and error is working fine when nothing is inputted. 
But when input username and password. nothing happens. no error in logcat or activity.

[image]

Login Activity

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/loginpage"
    tools:context=".loginpage">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:text="SignIn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="120dp"
        android:text="Register"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editUsername"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editUsername" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editUsername"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editUsername"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/oelogo" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Login Java

```
    FirebaseDatabase database;


  DatabaseReference users;

    EditText editUsername, editPassword;
    Button btnSignIn, btnRegister;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loginpage);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        users = database.getReference("Login");

        editUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUsername);
        editPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPassword);

        btnSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent s = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), staffregisterpage.class);
                startActivity(s);
            }
        });

        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                signIn(editUsername.getText().toString(),
                        editPassword.getText().toString());
            }
        });

    }

    private void signIn(final String username, final String password) {
        users.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.child(username).exists()) {
                    if (!username.isEmpty()) {
                        User login = dataSnapshot.child(username).getValue(User.class);
                        if (login.getPassword().equals(password)) {
                            Toast.makeText(loginpage.this, "Success Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent home = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),homepage.class);
                            startActivity(home);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(loginpage.this, "Wrong Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else
                        Toast.makeText(loginpage.this, "Username not registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Model/User Java

```
private String username;
    private String password;


    public User(String username, String password){
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;

    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth)?

Answer (score 0):

The A in the username is lowercase where as in the database reference it is capital.

[image]

This line will not return true.

```
if (dataSnapshot.child(username).exists())
```

---

To answer your other question yes firebaseAuthentication is much easier than this.